# How to make repeated HTTP requests not more than every N seconds with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to make HTTP request to an API endpoint again and again (forever), use previous value on every step (providing live "delta"). That API endpoint is throttled so I cannot make more than 5 requests per minute.

So if previous request took > 1/5 minute then we fire next request immediately. Otherwise we wait for 1/5 minute.

As a mean of using previous value on each step I thought about `expand` but how to combine this with `interval`/`timer` not to make requests too often?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to create an Observable invoking a function such as the following

```
const callStream = (apiThrottleTime: number) => {
    let inputFromPreviousCall;
    return interval(apiThrottleTime).pipe(
        mergeMap(i => {
            console.log('Call counter: ' + i, 'Input from previous call: ' + inputFromPreviousCall);
            return callSimulation(inputFromPreviousCall)
        }, 1),
        tap(result => inputFromPreviousCall = result),
    );
}
```

and then subscribe to it, passing the throttle time of your API as input variable, e.g. like

```
const apiThrottleTime = 1000;
callStream(apiThrottleTime).subscribe();
```

the API call is simulated with this code

```
let callCounter = 0;
const callSimulation = (inputFromPreviousCall: number) => {
    const call = new Subject<any>();
    setTimeout(() => {
        call.next(callCounter);
        callCounter++;
        call.complete();
    }, Math.random()*4000);
    return call.asObservable();
};
```

The idea is the following

1. With `interval` you create the *rhythm* of notification you want to
   have at the base, which is the throttle time of your API
2. Each time this *rhythm clock* ticks, then you call the API, which
   returns an Observable
3. You create a new stream, merging such new Observables with
   `mergeMap`, keeping the *concurrency level* at 1 - the concurrency
   level is set via the second optional parameter of `mergeMap`
4. The fact that you have the *concurrency level* set to 1 ensures that the
   sequence of notifications of the resulting Observable is maintained
   the same as the sequence of notifications of the *rhythm clock*,
   i.e. the sequence of the calls to the API is maintained, which is
   crucial if you want to use the result of the previous call as input
   to the next - note the `mergeMap` with *concurrency level* set to 1 is the same as `concatMap`
5. The result of a call is stored in the variable `inputFromPreviousCall`, local to the function `callStream`, and is used in the subsequent call to the API

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
export const onePerInterval = <T>(intervalMs: number) =>
    (observable: Observable<T>) => observable.pipe(
        concatMap(val => interval(intervalMs).pipe(take(1), map(() => val)))
    )
```